# scroll to a set of elements on screen with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to write a jquery function that will take a number of div elements by id or class and the screen scroll so that they are in view. I know that this may not be possible if the divs are spread over the page and not possible to get all in view, but would like to be able to get some in view for the user to be aware off.

Any tips on how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a selector you can just use [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to go to the *first* element the selector matches, like this:

```
$(window).scrollTop($(".selector").scrollTop());
```

Or to animate it so it's not an immediate jump there, use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".selector").scrollTop() }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll the window to an element, you could use the [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin for jQuery.

```
$.scrollTo('#focusOnMe');
```

You can visit [this page](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to view some demos of the plugin at work.

Comment: Thanks but would prefer not to use an external plugin

Comment: @Niall: Any particular reason? Why reinvent the wheel and kill bugs that have been dead a while? Actually I can provide a [similar plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) You can reuse the code at your own will.

Answer (score 0):

without jquery plugin
$(window).scrollTop($("#destinationDiv").offset().top );